# Convert string to same format

Tags: php, string, time, format

I have the five following strings (they are supposed to act like time):
11-20
9:30-20:00
8-20
7-16,30
9.30-9.50

I wonder if there is any way to convert them all to the format HH.HH-MM-MM.
For example 11-20 should be converted to 11.00-20.00.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
$str = '11-20 9:30-20:00 8-20 7-16,30 9.30-9.50';
$result = preg_replace_callback('~([\d:,.]+)~', function($i) {
    $i[1] = str_replace(array(',', '.'), ':', $i[1]);
    if (strpos($i[1], ':') === false) {
        $i[1] .= ':00';
    }

    return $i[1];
}, $str);
var_dump($result);
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/2esU4N

Answer (score 1):

building in what zerkms did I came up with this

```
<?php
class timeString {

public function timeString($string) {
        $exp = explode('-', $string);
        $timeString = array();
        foreach ($exp as $value) {
           $timeString[]= $this->normTime($value);
        }
        $time = implode('-', $timeString);
        return $time;
    }
 public function normTime($string) {
        $result = preg_replace_callback('~([\d:,.]+)~', function($i) {
                    $i[1] = str_replace(array(',', ':'), '.', $i[1]);
                    if (strpos($i[1], '.') === false) {
                        $i[1] .= '.00';
                    }

                    return $i[1];
                }, $string);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

this will return exactly what you asked for `11.00-20.00`.

Good Luck.